# How to use CouchRest with Sunspot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, couchdb, sunspot, couchrest

I have a problem with integration between CouchRest and Sunspot. When I search the book detail, the result from Sunspot is empty. I try to google it for a long time but no help.

```
Started GET "/books/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=Book of Life&commit=Search%21" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-08 11:27:41 +0700
Processing by BooksController#search as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"?", "query"=>"Book of Life", "commit"=>"Search!"}
Rendered books/index.html.erb within layouts/application (10.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 145ms (Views: 20.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
[] <-- I got empty result
```

## My System

- Ruby 1.9.2p290
- Rails 3.0.10
- CouchDB 1.1.0

## File structure ( https://gist.github.com/1164637/ )

- Model (/app/models/book_detail.rb)
- Controller (/app/controllers/books_controller.rb)
- Sunspot Adapter for CouchRest (/config/initializers/couchdb.rb)
- Sunspot Adapter Module (/config/initializers/sunspot_couch.rb)

NOTE: Sorry about code link. I always got "Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button". I try to remove all tab and follow SO code formatting guideline but it not work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me if I'm missing something, but I can't see how Sunspot is mapping "keywords" to the searchable fields on your CouchRest objects.

To debug first I'd visit Couch in the browser admin UI to make sure my that end is working. Then I'd double check that sunspot is getting anything. If sunspot contains your records then the bug is on the search side, if it is empty that maybe something is up with the object lifecycle management code it injects into your model class.

It's been ages since I did any serious Ruby, wish I could be more helpful. One option is to take advantage of some of the direct CouchDB full text offerings like CouchDB Lucene: https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene